# Can I Serialize XML straight to a string instead of a Stream with C#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

[This example](http://bytes.com/groups/net-xml/177700-how-do-i-serialize-object-string-instead-stream) uses a `StringWriter` to hold the serialized data, then calling `ToString()` gives the actual `string` value:

```
Person john = new Person();
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, john);
string serializedXML = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Is there any easier/Cleaner way to do this?  All of the `Serialize()` overloads seem to use a `Stream` or Writer.

**UPDATE:** Asked a similar question about [serializing an IEnumerable via an Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138667/extension-method-for-serializing-an-ienumerablet-object-to-a-string-array) .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Fun with extension methods...

```
var ret = john.ToXmlString()
```

---

```
public static class XmlTools
{
    public static string ToXmlString<T>(this T input)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            input.ToXml(writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
    public static void ToXml<T>(this T objectToSerialize, Stream stream)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
    }

    public static void ToXml<T>(this T objectToSerialize, StringWriter writer)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
    }
}
```

Comment: beaten... by... 9... seconds... aaarrrggghhh!

Comment: Ah yes!  Totally forgot about that!

Comment: yay... I am normally the late poster for making sure my code works before I submit it.

Comment: me too, but it's an attitude that doesn't pay off :)

Comment: Is this really an appropriate use of extension methods? I personally believe it is not, but such an opinion wouldn't warrant a vote down so I didn't (just so you don't think so if someone else did).

Comment: Extension methods allow for easier to read code.  You can do somethings like faking duck/dynamic typing and multiple base classes.  If people want to deal with calling factory/converter classes then do it way way.  You could always just use this as "string ret = XmlTools.ToXmlString(john)" but that just doesn't read as nice.

Comment: Using a generic method, in this case, wouldn't give a problem in case you serialize an object through a base reference?

Comment: you could provide the generic paramater if you wanted to serialize as a baseclass.  But you will most probably lose information if you do that.

Comment: My point was that in this case it woulb be better to rely on the GetType method...

Comment: Why do you say that?  You don't need to provide the type to the generic and it will automatically be the type of the object provided.  Only if you explicitly provided a generic parameter would you have to worry.

Comment: ugh ...and this is why we now use JSON

Answer (score 7):

More or less your same solution, just using an extension method:

```
static class XmlExtensions {

    // serialize an object to an XML string
    public static string ToXml(this object obj) {
        // remove the default namespaces
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        // serialize to string
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        xs.Serialize(sw, obj, ns);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }

}

[XmlType("Element")]
public class Element {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name;
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Element el = new Element();
        el.name = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(el.ToXml());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a different way of doing things, and a complete example!

Comment: This is missing `using` around `StringWriter`, it might not cause any issue in this case, but it should always be there just in case it is changed to take a stream.

Answer (score 5):

I created this helper method, but I haven't tested it yet.  Updated the code per orsogufo's comments (twice):

```
private string ConvertObjectToXml(object objectToSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, objectToSerialize);

    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What are you using Convert.ChangeType for?

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that I needed to cast it back to the right type...  but I think you're right, there is no need.  Code will be updated.

Comment: Infact no, the serializer takes a generic object as parameter (therefore your extra conversion is wasted). Also note that you don't need to pass the type explicitly, you can ask the object which is its type. Unless, of course, you want to serialize an object as an object of a different type (cannot see why you would want that, but you never know).

Comment: Trying to serialize an object as another type probably wouldn't work, unless it was a base class or interface I would assume.  Going to update my code to remove the type reference then.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like no body actually answered his question, which is no, there is no way to generate an XML string without using a stream or writer object.

Comment: Since the `Serializer` uses write internally it can't take a `String` or `StringBuilder` directly, the `StringWriter` has essentially no overhead, so don't see any issue with this.