# Extension Method for serializing an IEnumerable<T> object to a string array?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

[My last question was about getting the string representation of an object serialized to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138414/can-i-serialize-xml-straight-to-a-string-instead-of-a-stream-with-c).   One of the responders wrote an extension method to encapsulate the serialization process.

My question now is how can I use an Extension Method to return an array of strings, when passed an `IEnumerable<T>` object, where each `string` in the array would be an individually serialized element of the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using the code example from your link, you could add another method like this or convert them into array using ToArray() method.

```
public static class XmlTools
{
  public static IEnumerable<string> ToXmlString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inputs)
  {
     return inputs.Select(pArg => pArg.ToXmlString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly of interest: the research language Cω (where some of the ideas of Linq were first prototyped) defined your example method automatically. `IEnumerable<T>` would effectively have methods with the same names as the methods of `T`, except the return type `R` would become `IEnumerable<R>`. It was like `Select` being built into the language in a very succinct way.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your next several questions...

```
new XElement("people", myPeople.ToXElements());
```

---

```
public static class XmlTools
{
    public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this T input)
    {
        return XElement.Parse(input.ToXmlString());
    }
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> ToXElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        foreach (var item in input)
            yield return input.ToXElement();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToXmlString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        foreach (var item in input)
            yield return item.ToXmlString();
    }
    public static string ToXmlString<T>(this T input)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            input.ToXml(writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
    public static void ToXml<T>(this T objectToSerialize, Stream stream)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
    }

    public static void ToXml<T>(this T objectToSerialize, StringWriter writer)
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write my extension method to produce a new IEnumerable rather than an array:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> XmlSerializeAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    foreach (T item in input)
    {
        yield return item.ToXmlString();
    }
}
```

You can get the array you want easily by using

```
var myArray = myEnumerable.XmlSerializeAll().ToArray();
```

This way, you add some flexibility. It's possible to produce a List instead, or use infinitely long enumerations if you like :)