# How to serialize a .NET object and assign to a string variable?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

How do I serialize a .NET object into XML and assign the XML string to variable?

Example:

```
private void SerializeObject(string filename)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Writing With Stream");

    XmlSerializer serializer =
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));
    OrderedItem i = new OrderedItem();
    i.ItemName = "Widget";
    i.Description = "Regular Widget";
    i.Quantity = 10;
    i.UnitPrice = (decimal) 2.30;
    i.Calculate();

    // Create a FileStream to write with.
    Stream writer = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

    // Serialize the object, and close the TextWriter
    serializer.Serialize(writer, i);

    //Assign the serialized XML to a variable here.
    //For example, var serialized=serializer.serialized(i);

    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138414/can-i-serialize-xml-straight-to-a-string-instead-of-a-stream-with-c

Comment: The example here works: https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/serialize-an-object-to-string-and-from-string-back-to-object/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
Test t = new Test() { Id = 1 };

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ser.Serialize(ms, t);
ms.Position = 0;

StreamReader r = new StreamReader(ms);
string res = r.ReadToEnd();
```

***EDIT***:  @Quasdunk not only beat me, but with a better code sample

Comment: lol - sorry, bro :) But at least you shared your own sample, so +1 for that!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do here is to use a `StringWriter`:

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(sw, obj);
string xml = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: serializer.Serialize(sw, obj); on line 2?

Comment: @JanT typo, fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter() && XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem)))
{
    xml.Serializer(sw, i);
    string result = sw.ToString();
}
```

This assumes that `i` is an `OrderedItem` (as per your post).

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it:

```
using(var mem = new MemoryStream()){
    serializer.Serialize(mem,"");
    String xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
}
```